# FFMPEG - concat demuxer with duration filter issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to generate video from images using **ffmpeg concat demuxer**.I am creating a text file with image file path. Since images can be of different duration, i am using **duration** filter to specify the duration of each image. Sample text file is like :

> file 1.jpg
>
> duration 3
>
> file 2.jpg
>
> duration 3
>
> file 3.jpg
>
> duration 5

1.jpg and 2.jpg both are displayed for specified 3 sec each but 3.jpg comes for just 2 seconds.

FFMPEG command:

> ffmpeg -f concat -i D:/textfile.txt  -y -r 10 -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset veryfast D:/video.mp4

Comment: The duration directive doesn't work for the last entry, so add a single frame at the end i.e.`file 3.jpg`

Comment: i added `file 3.jpg` at end. total video duration came as 13 seconds. 3.jpg was there for 7 seconds instead of desired 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i textfile -y -vf fps=10 -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset veryfast video.mp4
```

where textfile is

```
file 1.jpg
duration 3
file 2.jpg
duration 3
file 3.jpg
duration 5
file 3.jpg
```

Comment: only change is to use -vf fps=10 instead of -r 10?

Comment: No. Also add last line in text.

Comment: that i added earlier as well. Then total video duration came to be 13 sec. 3.jpg was displayed for 7 sec instead of mentioned 5. But after using -vf fps=10 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

#### My usage

I'm facing a similar issue with different `ffmpeg` command options to concat a list of JPG images to an MP4 video.

FFmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

Command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i "input.txt" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mp4"
```

`input.txt`:

```
file '1.jpg'
duration 5
file '2.jpg'
duration 5
```

Reference: https://shotstack.io/learn/use-ffmpeg-to-convert-images-to-video/

---

#### The problem I'm facing

The resulting video only shows the 1st image for 5 seconds, but at the end of the video, I can see like a frame of the 2nd image.

From what I have tested so far, the issue only happens when I have `1` or `2` images. For `3` or more images, I get the expected result. For `3` images and `duration 5` applied to all `3` `file`s, the output duration is `14.967000` seconds (close to the expected duration of `15` seconds).

---

#### Findings

I can see from the below FFmpeg defect ticket that this is a known bug in the concat demuxer.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6128

---

#### Resolution

Whoever getting such kind of weird issues, no matter it's a misuse or bug, I think all we can do before it gets fixed in a future release is that, we need to do some hacks.

As Gyan commented below the question, you need to add one more `file` to the end of the input text file.

I tried but I'm not able to get the expected duration just like what OP replied Gyan.

Then for me, I'll just make the input file like this to just convert images to videos one by one:

```
file '1.jpg'
duration 5
file '1.jpg'
```

I get an output duration of `5.034000` seconds.

Then I'll just repeat the same process for the 2nd image, and concat the `2` videos with another `ffmpeg` command.

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i "concat_input.txt" -c copy "output.mp4"
```

`concat_input.txt`:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

The output duration is `10.068000`, very close to what I'm expecting.

---

#### Other info

The command to check video duration is:

```
ffprobe output.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v 0
```